# Generic typescript interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have seen some examples that make me thing it may work but I cannot get the following to work.  In the following, the `C` generic represents a class type and the `I` generic represents an interface type.  However, `return new SomeClass()`complains with: `Type SomeClass is not assignable to type I`.

```
class SomeFactory implements ISomeFactory {
    createSomeModule<C, I>(clas?: C, options?: IFactoryOptions): I {
            switch (typeof (clas)) {
                case 'SomeClass':
                    return new SomeClass(); 
                ...
            }
    }
}
```

Is that supposed to work as I'd like to?  Am I missing something?  Or that's just not supported.  I'm running VS Code with Typescript version 2.10.

Comment: `typeof` will always return `'object'`.

Comment: The switch statement works fine with `typeof`.  The issue is with the casting of `new SomeClass()` to generic interface `I`.

Comment: You can disable type checking with a: `return new SomeClass() as any;`

Comment: ok, thanks.  I have decided to remove the generic `I` and just explicitly OR-declare the possible interface types.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to `I`.

```
return <I>new SomeClass();
```

Or you can make `C` extend `I`.

```
createSomeModule<C extends I, I>
//...
return <C>new SomeClass();
```